# Getting rasa: command not found despite having installed rasa

Tags: python, linux, installation, pip, rasa

I'm trying to run rasa on an ubuntu system (recently updated to latest LTS version). I made a virtual environment with anaconda, installed pip and then rasa as shown in the documentation. However, I keep getting **rasa: command not found** when I tried running 'rasa init'

I followed the steps given on other similiar post:

**o** I uninstalled and reinstalled rasa

**o** My first installation was with pip3, the second with pip

**o** The second time, I opened the directory I wanted to work in, using cd, and installed there, and also ran 'pip3 install -U pip'

**o** I tried running 'rasa init --no-prompt' instead of 'rasa init' and got the same error

**o** I tried 'pip show rasa' ,and got
Name: rasa
Version: 0.0.5
...

**o** I tried 'pip list command' and rasa 0.0.5 was visible there

My installation came as successful, but I had this error:

> INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of rasa to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
> Collecting rasa
> Using cached rasa-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.1 kB)
> Using cached rasa-0.0.5-py3-none-any.whl
> Using cached rasa-0.0.4.tar.gz (5.0 kB)
> Using cached rasa-0.0.3.tar.gz (4.7 kB)
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: /home/anaconda3/envs/rasa-env/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nwwpljd_/rasa_c501d56996fa4242826f449fb9efb8bc/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nwwpljd_/rasa_c501d56996fa4242826f449fb9efb8bc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-oo59li03
> cwd: /tmp/pip-install-nwwpljd_/rasa_c501d56996fa4242826f449fb9efb8bc/
> Complete output (7 lines):
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/tmp/pip-install-nwwpljd_/rasa_c501d56996fa4242826f449fb9efb8bc/setup.py", line 14, in 
> with open('HISTORY.rst', 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
> File "/home/anaconda3/envs/rasa-env/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 905, in open
> file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'HISTORY.rst'
> ----------------------------------------
> WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/56/5d44415d54043fb441b910bf86fa36bbb3b5565a507ba4ea933117cf109f/rasa-0.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=409e502bc20a29db848b68766decacad15a9cbeb68d1afd90add9945945c9048 (from https://pypi.org/simple/rasa/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
> Using cached rasa-0.0.2.tar.gz (3.9 kB)
> Using cached rasa-0.0.1.tar.gz (1.6 kB)*

But after that, finally, it came as installation successful.

Please help me

**Edit: -** I have found out on the rasa forum that the problem was that my version of python was incompatible with Rasa. Problem solved!

Comment: Hey @Naik - perhaps best to head over to the Rasa Forum - https://forum.rasa.com - for getting help on installation issues.

Comment: Okay thank you, will try